# Usage report Smart TV , receiver, gaming consoles

Tags: measurement-devices, smart-home

I have a setup made up of:

1. LG OLED55C7V
2. Onkyo receiver NR636 - connected to the LG TV
3. PS4 Console connected to the Onkyo receiver
4. XBOX Console connected to the Onkyo receiver
5. Google Chromecast connected to the Onkyo receiver

All devices are connected via HDMI.

I would like to know how much time my kids are spending on the PS4 or XBOX or directly on the LG SmartTV e.g. on Disney+.

I searched a lot and software wise it's not possible: my LG TV has webOS 06.10.30 and LG will not update it to a newer webOS version.
PS4 and Disney+ do not offer any screen time report/parental controls. XBOX has.

Ideally I'd like to see how much the TV was on and used by Disney+ smart app, or from Onkyo via PS4 or XBOX. In the light of my research, I guess this is not possible, then the next best report would be ON
a) time the TV was on e.g. maybe via a smart plug that will check the W (wats) usage to infer the time when the TV was ON?
b) Usage from Onkyo on, ideally, time ON for each input e.g. PS4, if not possible, overall time that Onkyo was on
c) Any other way? e.g. electricity sockets for each device that can make the difference between the consumption when the device is on or off, knowing that some of the devices e.g. PS4 or XBOX are doing updates over night even in standby if I understood correctly

Many thanks